# Can't change location of widgets in KivyMD

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to move `MDLabel` and `MDRectangleFlatButton` to the center of the screen, but both `pos_hint` and `halign` are getting ignored.

`app.kv`:

```
ScreenManager:
   MainScreen:

<MainScreen>
   name: 'main_screen'
   BoxLayout:
      orientation: 'vertical'
      MDToolbar:
         title: 'My App'

      MDLabel:
         text: 'Welcome again!'
         pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
         style: 'H5'

      MDRectangleFlatButton:
         text: 'Enter'
         pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
```

`app.py`:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class MainScreen(Screen):
   pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main_screen"))

class MyApp(MDApp):

   def build(self):
      return Builder.load_file("app.kv")

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Please don't abuse blockquotes (`>`) for emphasis. They should be used for quotes _only_.

Comment: The `halign: 'center'` in the `MDLabel` works for me. Is that how you are using it?

Comment: @JohnAnderson `halign: 'center'` works for `MDLabel`, but doesn't work for `MDRectangleFlatButton`.

Comment: When I run your code, the `MDRectangleFlatButton` is centered horizontally. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @JohnAnderson I expected the `MDRectangleFlatButton` to be a little bit under the `MDLabel`, and that's what happens when I set `MDRectangleFlatButton` to `center_y: 0.4` and don't use `BoxLayout`.

Comment: I decided that `BoxLayout` wasn't a good choice in this scenario and switched to `FloatLayout`.

Comment: Sounds like a good choice.